# How to detect PayUMoney response without clicking Continue Shopping in Android?

Tags: android, redirect, response, payumoney

I integrated PayUMoney in my Android App but the problem is I am getting its response when I click on Continue shopping which is coming when payment completed or failed.
What I need is to get response without clicking anything.

[image]

This is the page which is coming when payment is completed or failed and I am getting response when I am clicking on this button "Continue Shopping".
I do not need this page I need to get response without clicking anything.

Comment: I also need this. Did you solve it?

Comment: @BhaskarJyotiDutta  use this code to startPayUmoneyflow.          PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(paymentParam, mActivity, R.style.AppTheme_default, false);

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to me. I  do not need the "Continue Shopping" page I need to get the response without clicking anything. How can I do that?